# Frage vs Anfrage

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the word "Frage" and the word "Anfrage"?

There are many cases in which seems that they would be interchangable, but in some cases I get weird faces, so I guess it is not always so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are very similar and can often be used synonymously, but there are differences.

A [Anfrage](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anfrage) is a request. You use it to ask for something. For example:

> Haben Sie meine Anfrage bezüglich des Auftrags erhalten?
>
> (Did you get my request regarding the contract?)

A [Frage](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Frage) is a question.

> Ich habe eine Frage zu dieser Aufgabe.
>
> (I have a question about this task.)